# how to we can get records from two table using Relationships in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want that news should also come with all given reviews on it.Help will be highly appriciated.
This is News Model

```
<?php
namespace Modules\Newsletter\Entities;
use Brexis\LaravelWorkflow\Traits\WorkflowTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class News extends Model {
use WorkflowTrait;

protected $table = 'news_info';
protected $fillable = [
'title', 'header', 'description', 'status', 'created_by', 'media_url', 'media_thumbnail',
];

    public function reviews() {
        return $this->hasMany(NewsReview::class,'reviewable_id');
    }

}
```

This is NewsReview Model

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Newsletter\Entities;

use App\User;
//use Hyn\Tenancy\Abstracts\TenantModel as TenancyModel;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class NewsReview extends Model {
    use SoftDeletes;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'review_text',
        'review_reaction',
        'is_visible',
        'reviewed_by',
        'reviewable_id',
        'reviewable_type'
    ];

    public function reviewable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function reviewer() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'reviewed_by');
    }
}
```

This is my controller function

```
public function newsReview($news){
        $review = News::find($news);
    $newsReview=$review->reviews;

    return $newsReview;
```

This is the output I am getting by this

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "review_text": null,
        "review_reaction": "hiie this is revieew",
        "is_visible": 1,
        "reviewed_by": 1,
        "reviewable_id": 1,
        "reviewable_type": "Modules\\Newsletter\\Entities\\News",
        "created_at": "2020-07-22 14:50:39",
        "updated_at": "2020-07-22 14:50:39",
        "deleted_at": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "review_text": null,
        "review_reaction": "hiie this is revieew 2",
        "is_visible": 1,
        "reviewed_by": 1,
        "reviewable_id": 1,
        "reviewable_type": "Modules\\Newsletter\\Entities\\News",
        "created_at": "2020-07-22 15:04:25",
        "updated_at": "2020-07-22 15:04:25",
        "deleted_at": null
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "review_text": null,
        "review_reaction": "hiie this is revieew 3",
        "is_visible": 1,
        "reviewed_by": 1,
        "reviewable_id": 1,
        "reviewable_type": "Modules\\Newsletter\\Entities\\News",
        "created_at": "2020-07-22 15:04:35",
        "updated_at": "2020-07-22 15:04:35",
        "deleted_at": null
    },
```

I want that news should also come with all given reviews on it.Help will be highly appriciated.

Comment: `return News::with('reviews')->find($news);` will give you your news model and all its reviews, you can read more about eager loading [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eager load the `reviews` relationship when retrieving the `news` model from the database:

```
public function newsReview($news)
{
    return News::with('reviews')->find($news);
}
```

this will return the `news` model and all of its `reviews` nested in the relations property.

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship
> data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not
> actually loaded until you first access the property. However, Eloquent
> can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model.

```
class Book extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the author that wrote the book.
     */
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Author');
    }
}

$books = App\Book::with('author')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel eager loading and inside the `News` model use the proerty `$with`, which will tell laravel to fetch all reviews associated with a news instance, like so

```php
class News extends Model {
use WorkflowTrait;

protected $table = 'news_info';
protected $fillable = [
'title', 'header', 'description', 'status', 'created_by', 'media_url', 'media_thumbnail',
];

   protected $with= ['review']; <-----------

    public function reviews() {
        return $this->hasMany(NewsReview::class,'reviewable_id');
    }

}
```

this way, whenever you fetch a `News` model, its reviews will be fetched too!, however if you dont want every query to have the reviews, only specific queries, then you can do this

```php
News::with(['review'])->get()
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you change the NewsReview table's reviewer relation function with

```
public function reviewer(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

thanks